# Kerberos- Why create SPN with NetBIOS and FQDN?

Tags: kerberos, setspn

I've setup Kerberos in my farm and things seem to be running right, i'm coming across articles that talk about registering the NetBIOS names of my webapps however and i'm curious as to why i would need to do that when I have already done it with the FQDN and things are working ok from what i can tell.

Can anyone shed any light as to why the NetBIOS SPNs would need to be created in my KDC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A question probably better served by ServerFault.

You need an SPN for each type of connection that may be made.  Because your configuration uses FQDN's you are not having issues connecting via SPN listening for that FQDN. if you tried to pass a kerberos token via the NetBIOS designation you would fail and receive an error stating the specified SPN could not be found.

For SharePoint deployments it is common to use a NetBios name for internal URL's and thus the recommendations to configure a SPN with NetBIOS.

Comment: i'll take that, pretty much best practice it seems, just incase the protocol is used. Following up with the suggestion found the resource you mentioned that i didn't know about so for others that don't as well : http://serverfault.com/